# Preventing relatively positioned div from pushing down content

Tags: html, css

How can I prevent relatively positioned div from pushing down content that follows? In following example I am trying to display a small green div on top of a bigger red one but the next red div gets pushed down when the green div appears.

If there is a better way of doing this, I'd appreciate tips.

Here is a running example: http://jsfiddle.net/38Rqh/

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">

.top {
  display: none;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}

.bottom {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.bottom:hover + div {
    display: block;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="bottom">

</div>
<div class="top">Displaying data</div>

<div class="bottom">

</div>
<div class="top">Displaying data</div>

<div class="bottom">

</div>
<div class="top">Displaying data</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`relative` still takes up space.  What you need is `absolute`.  One possibility is to set your `.bottom` elements to `position: relative` and then place the `.top` elements within them and position them absolutely.

http://jsfiddle.net/38Rqh/1/

```
.top {
  display: none;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
}

.bottom {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

.bottom:hover .top {
    display: block;
}
```

```
<div class="bottom">
<div class="top">Displaying data</div>
</div>

<div class="bottom">
<div class="top">Displaying data</div>
</div>
```

In this way, the `.top` elements will be positioned in relation to their containing `.bottom`.

This has the added benefit of not hiding the `.top` when hovering on the `.top` itself, causing the flicker you see in your example.

Answer (score 2):

I may have mixed this up with what should be appearing where, but using wrapper divs and position absolute instead of relative will get rid of the extra space.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">

.top {
  display: none;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
}

.bottom {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.bottom:hover + .top {
    display: block;
}

.wrapper { position: relative; }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bottom">

  </div>
  <div class="top">Displaying data</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bottom">

  </div>
  <div class="top">Displaying data</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bottom">

  </div>
  <div class="top">Displaying data</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```